# Are Telegram Bots able to view edited messages?

Tags: php, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

With the new edit features in telegram, are bots able to view edited messages?

By reading the API, I found that bots can only edit messages but not view edited messages.

Comment: Guessed as much sigh

Comment: Thanks for the reply though haha thought i missed smth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news, API now supports to view edited messages via `Update.edited_message`!

More info here:

- https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update

Or if you are using `python-telegram-bot`:

- http://pythonhosted.org/python-telegram-bot/telegram.html?highlight=telegram.update#telegram.Update

Comment: NICE GOOD JOB DEVS *THUMBS UP*